# An API error does not appear with a promise?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I made a request to upload a file and I purposely took the wrong file format to generate an error. During the request the promise is pending but is not rejected.

```
/**
 * TODO : ERREUR API A CORRIGER
 * onSubmit : Rappel le composent parent au click du boutton
 */
async onSubmit() {
  try {
    // upload des fichiers
    const uploadPromises = this.fichiers.map((fichier) =>
      ressourceSousEnsembleService.createFichierRessourceSousEnsemble(
        fichier
      )
    );
    console.log(uploadPromises); // Promesse pending
    const uploadResults = await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    // création de la ressource
    const ressourceToCreate = {
      titre: this.titre,
      note: this.note,
      urls: uploadResults.map((upload) => upload.url),
    };
    const ressource =
      await ressourceSousEnsembleService.createRessourceSousEnsemble(
        this.sousensemble.id,
        ressourceToCreate
      );
    this.handleSuccess(ressource);
  } catch (error) {
    this.handleErrors(error);
  }
},
```

Comment: Voting to close because needs more detail to be given a proper answer.